# Proving Two Exponential Equations are Equivalent

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Prove that the following equations are equivalent, for $x$ belonging to all real numbers.

$2^{2x-1}=\frac{1}{2^{2x}-1}$ and $2^{2x+1}=\frac{1}{2^{2x-1}-1}$

My work: With the left equation I see $2^{2x-1}=\frac{1}{4^x-1}=\frac{1}{(2^x-1)(2^x+1)}$ and right equation is $2^{2x+1}=\frac{1}{4^x-2}$. Maybe logs are helpful but can't see the log properties that would be useful.

Comment: The transformation of the right equation is wrong.

Comment: no, you cannot separate the exponents like that

Comment: They aren't equivalent (if by equivalent you mean they have the same solution set). $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is a solution of the first but not the second.

Comment: The problem does say for x belonging to all real numbers. Does that change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations $$2^{2x-1}=\frac{1}{2^{2x}-1}$$ and $$2^{2x+1}=\frac{1}{2^{2x-1}-1}$$ are not equivalent.

Note that $x=1/2$ satisfies the first one but it does not satisfy the second one.

Also $x=\log_4 (1/2 +\sqrt2)$ satisfies the second one but it does not satisfy the first one.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $\log_4$ instead of $\ln_4$?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for your attention, I fixed it in my solution.